# How can I use an object as a parameter of its own method in Rust?

Tags: methods, rust, borrow-checker, mutability

I wrote the following code for a simple struct in Rust. This is just an example, it doesn't have much real logic:

```
struct Vec2 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

impl Vec2 {
    fn multiply(&mut self, other: &Vec2) {
        self.x *= other.x;
        self.y *= other.y;
    }
}
```

I can create simple vectors and multiply a vector with another vector, but I encountered a problem when I tried to multiply a vector with itself: The compiler complains that I can't borrow that vector as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable.

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec2 { x: 2.0, y: 2.3 };
    vec.multiply(&vec);
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `vec` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 |     vec.multiply(&vec);
   |     ^^^^--------^----^
   |     |   |        |
   |     |   |        immutable borrow occurs here
   |     |   immutable borrow later used by call
   |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

This makes sense, but what would be the correct way to multiply such a vector with itself? And more importantly: for the general case where I need to modify a struct with its own method with that same struct as parameter.

Comment: The easiest solution in this particular case is to derive `Copy` for `Vec2`, and accept `other` by value rather than by reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you understand this already, but the reason that what you have now doesn't work is that a value cannot be mutably borrowed at the same time as an immutable borrow. To perform the method as is, you would need both the mutable borrow (in the form of `&mut self`) and the immutable borrow (in the form of `other: &Vec2`) *at the same time*. Since your method should work for any two members of `Vec2`, you'll always have two separate borrows: the compiler can't deduce that a single borrow would work for the case of multiplying the vector by itself.

As for your question, you have several options, depending on the details of what you're trying to do.

## Option 1: cloning

Simply add `#[derive(Clone)]` to your definition of `Vec2` and you'll be able to clone an element of that type using the `clone` method.

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Vec2 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

impl Vec2 {
    fn multiply(&mut self, other: &Vec2) {
        self.x *= other.x;
        self.y *= other.y;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec2 { x: 2.0, y: 2.3 };
    vec.multiply(&vec.clone());
}
```

## Option 2: copying

If your type is this simple (just two floats), then you could reasonably also derive `Copy`. Then elements of the type are simply copied when fed to functions, rather than needing a reference. That means that we should change the signature of `Vec2::multiply` to take `other` as simply `Vec2`, rather than `&Vec2` (this isn't strictly necessary, but taking a pointer is usually less efficient for `Copy` types).

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Vec2 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

impl Vec2 {
    fn multiply(&mut self, other: Vec2) {
        self.x *= other.x;
        self.y *= other.y;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec2 { x: 2.0, y: 2.3 };
    vec.multiply(vec);
}
```

## Option 3: a dedicated method

You could have a separate method called `multiply_self` or `square` (depending on your semantics) that just takes `&mut self`. This might be your best bet in the general case of modifying a struct using itself.

```
struct Vec2 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

impl Vec2 {
    fn multiply_self(&mut self) {
        self.x *= self.x;
        self.y *= self.y;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec2 { x: 2.0, y: 2.3 };
    vec.multiply_self();
}
```

## Option 4: return a new value

You could have a method that doesn't take `self` mutably and instead returns a new `Vec2`. Then you could do `vec = vec.multiply(&vec)`.

```
struct Vec2 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

impl Vec2 {
    fn multiply(&self, other: &Vec2) -> Vec2 {
        Vec2 {
            x: self.x * other.x,
            y: self.y * other.y,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec2 { x: 2.0, y: 2.3 };
    vec = vec.multiply(&vec)
}
```

There are probably lots of other ways to do this, but this is what comes to mind in this simple case. If you share more details about what your trying to do in general, I might be able to come up with more.